# CISCO 887va-w-e-k9 Configuration

Tags: cisco

I am trying to configure a CISCO router using the GUI.

When I click on WiFi, CISCO remains stuck with the message, "Obtaining connection details of Wi-Fi interfaces".

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: What version of Java do you have?

Comment: I tried first with Java 6, then I upgraded to Java 8.

Comment: (This is just a side-note comment: Cisco GUI is terrible. Learn CLI.)

Comment: Is that Cisco Configuration Professional there?

Comment: I don't know. I could access to it initially from 10.10.10.1, then after some command lines, I opted for 192.168.1.1. I thought it was like any plain router.

Comment: What is written as the tab title. I can hardly read it.

Comment: Oh, yes "Cisco Configuration Professional".